# Xamarin project update from android 11 to android 13

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Since Android 11 is outdated i want to update it to 13, so with Visual Studio Comunnity im trying to update the project but when i try to archive it im getting this error:

```
AMM0000:
    android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <service#crc64a934e6823fae7e50.EmplealiaFirebaseIIDService>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
```

Also modified a bit the properties in "AndroidManifest.xml" in the directory Proyecto.Android/Properties

Tried changing other manifest that i think they auto generate when compiling or when archiving the project and didnt work i guess

Comment: You can [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) if it's helpful to others facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so apparently if your ussing firebase messaging and those things you have to make a change in the ...FirebaseIIDService.cs and the ...FirebaseIIDService.cs classes.
If you have this classes you may have to add inside `[Service]` tag the exported value`[Service(Exported = false)]` (set it on true if needed). This way when trying to archive, the Release manifests generated will have in  tags the exported value.